# Wrong order when setting xticks in matplotlib barplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, ordereddict

I'm trying to plot an OrderedDict using matplotlib. The dictionary **d** is sorted by value, in descending order:

> OrderedDict([(1, 792),
> (2, 199),
> (3, 18),
> (4, 8),
> (8, 3),
> (5, 2),
> (10, 2),
> (6, 1),
> (9, 1)])

This is the code I'm using to draw the barplot:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1)

axs.bar(d.keys(), d.values())
axs.set_xticks(list(d.keys()))
axs.set_yscale('log')
```

And this is the resulting plot:

[image]

In my idea the correct order for the x-axis labels is [1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 5, 10, 6, 9]. Why the bars are plotted in ascending order, instead?

Hon can I plot the bars following the same order of d?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numerical values are sorted automatically when plot, which makes more sense. If you want to make sure you have the correct order, you can plot each bar manually:

```
for i,k in enumerate(d.keys()):
    axs.bar(i, d[k])

axs.set_xticks(range(len(d)))
axs.set_xticklabels(d.keys())
axs.set_yscale('log')
```

Output:

[image]

Or you can turn the keys into string:

```
axs.bar(list(map(str,d.keys()) ), d.values()) 
axs.set_yscale('log')
```

Output:

[image]